# BizTalk 2013 HL7 assembler replaces national characters with question marks

Tags: character-encoding, biztalk, hl7, biztalk-2013

When I try to produce a HL7 encoded message from through the HL7 assembler in BizTalk 2013 all national characters like å,ä,ö are replaced with a question mark.

I have promoted the property http://HL7Schemas.HeaderPropertySchema#MessageEncoding with the value 65001 but the output file is not UTF-8.

Does anyone have any experience from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating the message parts in  pipeline component instead of in an orchestration. What I had missed was setting the Charset property to "utf-8" on the new message parts.

Comment: Also be aware that there is an bug in the Charset property in the send pipeline.  If you set it via the Administration Console it does not take effect.  You have to set it in Visual Studio and deploy it with the correct setting.  This bug is in all version of BizTalk up to BizTalk 2010.  I haven't verified if it exists in 2013 / 2013 R2 yet.